Cannot use @ or See Run tests in vscode for Salesforce DX
I'm not able to see the Run All Test | Run Test action in vscode on a test class or test method. Also I'm not able to use the @ to find methods definitions/variable declarations. I tried these:

Restart vscode
Restart extensions

This works for sometime, I.e., when I restart, I'm able to see the run tests action and use @ to navigate. But after sometime, the run tests disappears and @ won't give any results.
I was on JAVA 17:

reinstalled all sfdx extensions - didn't work

Changed to Open JDK from Microsoft

reinstalled vscode + extensions  - didn't work

Changed to Zulu Open JDK 17

reinstalled vscode + extensions, cleared all vscode data. Still the same. It works for sometime and then back to square one.

Settings:


You should consider logging a bug over on the public repo. They will be able to better guide you on the information they need to troubleshoot/fix the problem. As for general suggestions, try increasing the Java memory from 1024 to 2048, see if that helps, or leaving blank for the default memory allocation.
